# Formula to get Current date when a change is made

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, date

I have a simple SharePoint item list .
Consider this specific spreadsheet for an example, but I need an general solution to work as a Excel formula.

A1: contains a date.
B1:Status contains a  status Available/unavailable/.
C1:LastAvailable date  has nothing and should get result.
When a change is made to B1, I want to get notified about it and the resulting formula's update in C1 with the date of update.

I tried multiple methods to work, but this is working in Excel with the helop of MAcro and  functions such as TODAY() and NOW().
I am unable to accomplish this on Sharepoint.

```
IF(B:B="Available",TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mm"),IF(ISBLANK(Status),"","NULL"))
```

Above is the formula which I used to get the state change from unavailable to Available . 
Similarly below one for vice versa

```
=IF(B:B="Assigned",TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mm"),IF(ISBLANK(Status),"","NULL"))
```

**Note**: I dont have access to Sharepoint server, Unable to use Sharepoint designer.

Comment: For notification, you can use sharepoint default alert notifications. For date, I would have recommended you to use workflow. But you don't have an access to designer.

Comment: Hello @GaneshSanap, Thanks for the suggestion. In case if I have access to designer what are the steps to create workflow. I am new to SharePoint and I am using SharePoint 2007

Answer (score 0):

as I am reading the requirement, you want to hold the 'Last Available Date' when the Status changes from 'Available' to 'Unavailable'. For such requirement, calculated columns are not best fit. I would recommend you to use, either Workflow/MSFlow or use Event Receiver/Remote Event Receiver/Webhook (based on your environment). The reason is, you cannot use circular references in SP Calculated columns to retain 'Last Available Date' values, also from SP Formula syntax `IF(condition, TRUE, FALSE)` you cannot eliminate else condition like in traditional programming.

Using the below formula, you can store the current time stamp when the `Status` column change to available, and put the minimum date when it changes back to 'Unavailable' like '01/01/01'.

`=IF([Status] = "Available", NOW(), "01/01/01")`

[image]

Also, as @Ganesh mentioned, you can subscribe to list alerts to notifications when a new Item is created, modified or deleted. If you want to notify only when the `Status` column changes to `Available`, then you need to have workflow on item created and modified action which send email alert.

Comment: Thanks for the response @ThinkB4Code. I tried using Workflow as well and I am out of logic.

Comment: Are you using SPD WF or MS Flow?

Answer (score -1):

This is how I would craft the equation in a Calculated Column in your list:
`=IF([Status] = "Available",TEXT([Modified],"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"),IF(ISBLANK([Status]),"","NULL"))`

1. Reference another SP Column by using its display name in brackets,
   e.g.: [Status] and [Modified]
2. You **cannot** use the volatile TODAY or NOW variables in SharePoint
   calculated columns if the formula has spaces in it.

***References:***

- [Examples of Columns in SharePoint Lists](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)
- [Understanding Calculated Columns](https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/calculated-columns-tutorial)

Comment: I disagree to your point number 2, as you can refer to `Today()` and `Now()` in calculated columns.